# xamarin : My masterDetailPage take the entire screen height

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem because my `masterDetailPage` takes the entire screen height. 
I would like my menu to open below the `ToolBar`.

I tried with `MasterBehavior="Popover"` but doesn't work

Can you help me ? 
Thanks ;)

Comment: I think this is not achievable through a simple setting. You will probably have to style your Master using paddings and margins to achieve the look you're going for.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem !

In projectName.Android/MainActivity.cs 
Just change

public class Main Activity global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.**FormsAppCompatActivity**

IN

public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.**FormsApplicationActivity**

And delete Theme="Yourtheme"